# Global Search does not return account results when searching by Zip Code + Lastname + Firstname (wildcard), but only cases

Tags: global-search

I'll really appreciate some help here. Do you know why Global Search does not return account results when searching by Zip Code + Lastname + Firstname (wildcard), but only cases?
[image]

Comment: In addition to the below answers, does Account (0) appear on the left of the results window? If not, click "Search All"

Comment: Yes, it does, Account (0). Where I can find this "search all" in the account object?

Comment: Ok, then search all is not going to fix it if Account(0) appears on the left

Answer (score 1):

From Salesforce [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Object-not-included-in-search-and-results-differ-for-users&language=en_US)

**Object not included in search and different among users**

**Knowledge Article Number  000233962**

**Description** :   If an object is not included in search results be sure to check that the object has a tab and that its tab visibility for the affected user's assigned profile is set to "Default On" or "Default Off" and not "Tab Hidden" and that the object's setting "Allow Search" is enabled.

**Resolution**

Differences among users for which objects are included in search can be the result of smart search as well as user's assigned profile's tab settings.
Users may see differing objects in their search results due to:

Smart Search attempting to return results for the objects that you use most frequently.

As a result, search may exclude objects from those initially returned and users may need to click "Search All" or "View More" to search additional or desired objects in search.

To expand the search to other objects in Salesforce Classic, click "Search All" located at the bottom of the list of objects in the left column within search results. If you don't have a Search All option, global search doesn't have enough information about which objects you use and results will already include all objects. Reference: How Do I Refine Search Results in Salesforce Classic?

In Lightning Experience each person's Top Results page is different depending on which objects they use the most. Use the "View More" link in case you want to see more results for an object. Reference: How Do I Refine Search Results in Lightning Experience?

As an example, when a user performs a search in production they may see a set of objects being included in their search results with the option to "Search All." Where as in sandbox, they may find that all objects are returned in search results. This difference in behavior would be explained by smart search being able to scope the users frequently used objects in production because that's where they're commonly working and using search. However, search may not have enough data to do the same in sandbox since the user may not be searching as frequently there as they are in production. This same explanation is also applicable for variations between different users in the same org as well.

It is not possible to disable or configure this default search behavior however, as a workaround users can pin objects in search results to ensure that they're automatically included in search results each time without having to click either "Search All" or "View More."

In addition, you may consider promoting the Idea, Global "Smart Search" not very smart so that we may see this functionality changed with a future release of Salesforce.

If the above information does not explain the situation and an object is still not included in search results check to ensure that:

1. Your custom object has a custom tab

Custom object records are searchable in the Salesforce user interface only if the custom object is associated with a custom tab. Reference: Searchable Fields: Custom Object.

2. User's assigned profiles have appropriate tab settings for the object

To allow your users to find a custom object’s records when they search the object's custom tab settings for users profiles must be set to Default On or Default Off. See Tab Settings for more details.

3. Ensure that the custom object's "Allow Search" is enabled

Note: By default, search is disabled for new custom objects however, in some circumstances Support working in conjunction with an org's administrator may have deliberately disabled this feature in order to improve search performance and indexing. That said, it's important to confirm whether or not this may be intentionally disabled before enabling. See Guidelines for Making Search Faster for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This info may also help you :

> A few things to note about searchable fields: Global search finds more
>   fields per object compared to other search types. By default, enhanced
>   lookups query a limited set of fields, primarily Name fields for each
>   object. If available in the enhanced lookup search dialog, select All
>   Fields and enter other search terms unique to the record, to search
>   through all searchable fields. You can't search encrypted, formula,
>   and lookup fields.

Details about all searchable Account fields:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_fields_business_accounts.htm&language=en_US